# Concat with two LIKEs MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I wanted to search in multiple fields within my table `catalog_form`. using Concat and LIKES (I used `foreach` to loop)

What am I missing? Thanks for all your help.

```
SELECT * 
FROM catalog_form 
WHERE CONCAT(image, acc_no, cat_no, art_type, title, mat_tech
            , acquired_by, dimensions, maker_pub, place_origin
             , location, description, encoded_by) LIKE '%maria%' 
             OR LIKE '%great%' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Any errors? What you posted should work as shown.

Comment: "What am I missing?" The question is missing a table structure, example data, expected output ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) ..

Answer (score 0):

You  should repeat the concat value for the OR clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM catalog_form 
WHERE CONCAT(image, acc_no, cat_no, art_type, title, mat_tech
            , acquired_by, dimensions, maker_pub, place_origin
             , location, description, encoded_by) LIKE '%maria%' 
OR 
      CONCAT(image, acc_no, cat_no, art_type, title, mat_tech
            , acquired_by, dimensions, maker_pub, place_origin
             , location, description, encoded_by) 
             LIKE '%great%' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: I am getting an error: "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given..." if i have two strings entered on my search bar, the word GREAT and MARIA. and NO error for a single string, either GREAT or MARIA. Thanks

Comment: the code seems correct try execute the code in a sql command env or in a sql IDE.... are you sure you are connected  to db ??

Comment: there is not A ORDER BY  in my code.. check yif you have an improper A

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this, I just placed the whole CONCAT before the second LIKE. Thanks for your time!!!